# How to know which page is calling an injected service in ASP.NET Blazor Server

Tags: asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a service that is injected and that is being called from specific Pages in my Blazor project.

That service is implementing some methods that need to know in which ASP.NET Blazor context/page they are being called.  I want to avoid passing this as a parameter to my methods and was hoping to get access to the name/type of the page that it is being called from.

Something like `IHttpContextAccessor` but instead of getting access to the HTTP context, I would love to get access to the Page object and perform logic based on that.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Sam, you should never pass component instances around.  They are owned by the Renderer.  The answer below shows you how to get either the url or the component type.  If the answer doesn't give you what you want: What actually information do you want? And how do you want to use it?

Comment: I want to inject my own Translator Service, that embeds the right IStringLocalizer , and to pick the right IStringLocalizer, I want to know which page is calling the service.  So I don't need the instance of a component or a page, I just need to know which type it is.

Answer (score 1):

## IF

all you need to know is the name, you could maybe get it from a [CallerFilePath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerfilepathattribute?view=net-7.0#examples) attribute on the method.

- Note that is a big IF

Another option would be to inject NavigationManager into your service (your service would need to be registered as scoped or transient) and get the current url from that.

Comment: That could indeed be a workaround, thanks

Comment: Hmm, when that logic is being called from within a component, then the CallerFilePath is that one of the component and not of the page, so I am not sure if it's what I need.  Thanks

Comment: Added another suggestion